# MeteorJs Template conditions to display different template

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-helper

I have a meteorjs default layout file and i am routing  to different pages using iron-route, What i am trying to do is not show navigation on the home page. I can do this by using two separate files but i want to do this with single file.

```
<template name="layout">

    <head>
        <title>
            {{title}}
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>

        {{> navigation }}

        <div class="nav_padding">
            {{> yield}}
        </div>


        {{> footer}}

    </body>

    </template>
```

My route

```
    Router.route('/', function(){
        this.layout('homeLayout');
        this.render('home', {
            data:{title: 'some'}
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this, but here's a simple solution...

Add a helper to your layout template which indicates if the nav should be shown based on the route name:

```
Template.myLayout.helpers({
  showNav: function() {
    return Router.current().route.getName() !== 'home';
  }
});
```

Modify your template to conditionally show the `navigation` template:

```
<template name="myLayout">
  {{#if showNav}}
    {{> navigation }}
  {{/if}}
  <div class="nav_padding">
    {{> yield}}
  </div>
  {{> footer}}
</template>
```

In order for your route to be [named](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#named-routes) you may need to modify your route to something like this:

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  template: 'home',
  layoutTemplate: 'myLayout',
  data: {title: 'some'}
});
```

Comment: do i change the body to layout because i have contained all this in template name layout

Comment: I updated the answer - if you are using IR, you actually should remove your body and put its contents into your layout template(s).

Comment: its still not working.....I tried printing the path to console and  for the homepage its showing undefined.

Comment: i changed the return statement to Router.current().route.getName() != undefined; and it works fine.....but  is there any  other way...?